# Looping on a joined table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple query in SQL server.

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.OrderNumber, p.PropertyUse
FROM  Orders o 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Properties p ON o.OrderID = p.OrderID
```

Each Order can has more than one Property.

I have to 'loop' for each Order (main table) through its properties (joined table), and to check- if one of the property has a propertyUse that IS NOT equal to 'x' I don't want this Order to come up on the results.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can also be solved with `NOT IN()` :

```
SELECT * FROM Properties t
WHERE t.OrderID NOT IN(SELECT s.orderID FROM Properties s
                       WHERE s.propertyUse = 'X')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I couldn't think of how to do it... I just changed my question and I want to make sure it is correct- If one of the propertyUse IS NOT equal to x than the order shouldn't come up on the results, so I changed your code to: WHERE s.propertyUse <> 'X'. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM Orders o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM Properties p
   WHERE o.OrderID = p.OrderID AND propertyUse = 'X')
```